# Using jlink command to create runtime image reports "Null charset name"

Tags: java, virtual-machine, java-11, jlink

I run following command:

```
D:\Program Files\jdk11>bin\jlink.exe --module-path jmods --add-modules java.desktop --output jre
```

And it leads to :

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null charset name
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(java.base/Charset.java:455)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(java.base/Charset.java:608)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(java.base/StringCoding.java:316)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(java.base/String.java:592)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(java.base/String.java:614)
        at java.lang.System.initProperties(java.base/Native Method)
        at java.lang.System.initPhase1(java.base/System.java:1942)
```

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: All the charsets that corresponding to supported configurations are in the java.base. Can you say something about the Windows system in particular which locale is this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with the option  **--suggest-providers java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider** at the end of your command.

Comment: bin\jlink.exe --module-path jmods --add-modules java.desktop --output jre --suggest-providers java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider      this command will output : this application cannot run on your computer.